# Given the following two assumptions, How to conclude $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}|\nabla g_r(y^{k})|=0 \ $?

Tags: convex-optimization, convexity, convex-analysis

Please refer attached 6-page short paper for details.

Let $M(y)=y+2r\nabla g_r(y)$.

Given $\ g_r(M(y^k))>g_r(y^k)+r|\nabla g_r(y^k)|^2, \forall k. \ $ (equation 36 in the paper)

and $ \ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}[g_r(y^{k+1})-g_r(M(y^k))]=0. $ (equation 33 in the paper)

Can anyone tell me how we can conclude $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}|\nabla g_r(y^{k})|=0 \ $?

---

Since there's a gap of index shift between these two equations and the result, I don't understand his logic. The author claimed to also use "$g_r$ bounded above" to reach this conclusion, but I don't see how.

---

Source: Page 561 of *The multiplier method of Hestenes and Powell applied to convex programming*, by R T Rockafellar

http://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr051-MultMethod.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Note that the conclusion is that the *gradient* of $g_r$ converges to zero, not $g_r$ itself!

The first inequality and the fact that $r>0$ imply
$$\ g_r(M(y^k)) - g_r(y^k) > r|\nabla g_r(y^k)|^2 \geq 0.$$
This implies 
$$\ g_r(M(y^k)) - g_r(y^{k+1})  + g_r(y^{k+1}) - g_r(y^k)> r|\nabla g_r(y^k)|^2 \geq 0.$$
A previous inequality (32) in the paper implies that $y^k$ has at most one cluster point. The additional boundedness of $g_r$ seems to imply that $y^k$ has a convergent subsequence, i.e. the whole sequence converges. This shows (compare to eq (33)) that $ g_r(y^{k+1}) - g_r(y^k)\to 0$ and 
from with the first equation you see that the whole left had side goes to zero.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that typo. However, can you please explain how LHS goes to zero? (since my second equation had slightly different index than your claim)

Comment: Oops. The argument is a little more involved…

Comment: Ok I see how this works. So if we don't have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\alpha_k}<\infty$ (used in (32)), then we don't have my conclusion, or it's not so trivial? (In a modified algorithm I'm analyzing, I only required $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_k<\infty$, which is weaker)